# java.io.Console support in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, console, java-io

I use the Eclipse IDE to develop, compile, and run my Java projects. Today, I'm trying to use the `java.io.Console` class to manage output and, more importantly, user input.

The problem is that `System.console()` returns `null` when an application is run "through" Eclipse. Eclipse run the program on a background process, rather than a top-level process with the console window we're familiar with.

Is there a way to force Eclipse to run the program as a top level process, or at least create a Console that the JVM will recognize? Otherwise, I'm forced to jar the project up and run on a command-line environment external to Eclipse.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470972/trying-to-read-from-console-java/26473083#26473083 I identified `System.out` and `System.in` to be sufficient for my use case and abondaned using `System.console()`.

Comment: I exported the project as the runnable jar, but i'm still getting console null error

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I assume you want to be able to use step-through debugging from Eclipse. You can just run the classes externally by setting the built classes in the bin directories on the JRE classpath.

```
java -cp workspace\p1\bin;workspace\p2\bin foo.Main
```

You can debug using the remote debugger and taking advantage of the class files built in your project.

In this example, the Eclipse project structure looks like this:

```
workspace\project\
                 \.classpath
                 \.project
                 \debug.bat
                 \bin\Main.class
                 \src\Main.java
```

**1. Start the JVM Console in Debug Mode**

**debug.bat** is a Windows batch file that should be run externally from a **cmd.exe** console.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET A_PORT=8787
SET A_DBG=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%A_PORT%,server=y,suspend=y
java.exe %A_DBG% -cp .\bin Main
```

In the arguments, the debug port has been set to *8787*. The *suspend=y* argument tells the JVM to wait until the debugger attaches.

**2. Create a Debug Launch Configuration**

In Eclipse, open the Debug dialog (Run > Open Debug Dialog...) and create a new **Remote Java Application** configuration with the following settings:

- *Project:* your project name
- *Connection Type:* Standard (Socket Attach)
- *Host:* localhost
- *Port:* 8787

**3. Debugging**

So, all you have to do any time you want to debug the app is:

- set a break point
- launch the batch file in a console
- launch the debug configuration

---

You can track this issue in [bug 122429](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429). You can work round this issue in your application by using an abstraction layer as described [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html).

Comment: I'd also put a `pause` at the end of that batch file so you can see any error messages that flash up before it closes.

Comment: This is the last straw for me.  If I have to do all of this just to debug, I am switching back to Netbeans.  So many unfixed bugs and UI annoyances in Eclipse it is not even funny.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo, this is just for remote debugging.  You can debug locally in eclipse without all of that.

Answer (score 33):

The workaround that I use is to just use System.in/System.out instead of Console when using Eclipse.  For example, instead of:

```
String line = System.console().readLine();
```

You can use:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Comment: I don't think that you would be able to read passwords with password masking that way.

Comment: ... and one need to handle `IOException`, which is not thrown in case of `Console.readLine()`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this occurs is because eclipse runs your app as a background process and not as a top-level process with a system console.

Answer (score 4):

Found something about this at http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=43 .

And sadly, since console is final, you can't extend it to create a  a wrapper around system.in and system.out that does it either. Even inside the eclipse console you still have access to those.  Thats probably why eclipse hasn't plugged this into their console yet...

I understand why you wouldn't want to have any other way to get a console other than System.console, with no setter, but i don't understand why you wouldn't want someone to be able to override the class to make a mock/testing console...

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a method to wrap up both options, and "fail over" to the System.in method when Console isn't available. The below example is a fairly basic one - you can follow the same process to wrap up the other methods in Console (readPassword, format) as required. That way you can run it happily in Eclipse & when its deployed you get the Console features (e.g. password hiding) kicking in.

```
    private static String readLine(String prompt) {
        String line = null;
        Console c = System.console();
        if (c != null) {
             line = c.readLine(prompt);
        } else {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                 line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                //Ignore    
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a class yourself. Following is an example:

```
public class Console {
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintStream ps;

    public Console(){
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ps = System.out;
    }

    public String readLine(String out){
        ps.format(out);
        try{
            return br.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public PrintStream format(String format, Object...objects){
        return ps.format(format, objects);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get a Console object from Eclipse.  I'd just make sure that console != null, then JAR it up and run it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to get a java.io.Console object when running an application through Eclipse. A command-line console window is not opened with the application, as it is run as a background process (background to Eclipse?). Currently, there is no Eclipse plugin to handle this issue, mainly due to the fact that java.io.Console is a final class.

All you can really do is test the returned Console object for null and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-read-input-from-console-keyboard-in-java/195) offers alternatives to using System.console(). One is to use a BufferedReader wrapped around System.in, the second is to use a Scanner wrapped around System.in.

Neither are as concise as console, but both work in eclipse without having to resort to debug silliness!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Eclipse workspace is C:\MyWorkspace, 
you created your java application inside a maven project MyProject, 
and your Java main class is com.mydomain.mypackage.MyClass.

In this case, you can run your main class that uses `System.console()` on the command line:

```
java -cp C:\MyWorkspace\MyProject\target\classes com.mydomain.mypackage.MyClass
```

NB1: if it's not in a maven project, check the output folder in project properties | Java Build Path | Source. It might not be "target/classes"

NB2: if it is a maven project, but your class is in src/test/java, you'll likely have to use "target\test-classes" instead of "target\classes"