# Java console API

Tags: java, console

I tried the `java.io.Console` API using eclipse. My sample code follows.

```
package app;

import java.io.Console;

public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Console console = System.console(); 
        console.printf("Hello, world!!");
    }

}
```

When I tried running the example, I got the following error.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   app.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)

Where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've mentioned in a comment that you're using Eclipse, it appears that there is currently no support for [`Console`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) in Eclipse, according to this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429).

The [`System.console`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()) method returns a console associated with the current Java virtual machine, and if there is no console, then it will return `null`. From the documentation of the `System.console` method:

> Returns the unique `Console` object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> The system console, if any, otherwise `null`.

Unfortunately, this the correct behavior. There is no error in your code. The only improvement that can be made is to perform a `null` check on the `Console` object to see if something has been returned or not; this will prevent a `NullPointerException` by trying to use the non-existent `Console` object.

For example:

```
Console c = System.console();

if (c == null) {
    System.out.println("No console available");
} else {
    // Use the returned Console.
}
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but I'd use System.err.println instead of System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

[System.console](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()) returns null if you don't run the application in a console. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide) for suggestions.

Comment: How to fix this? Should I have to run the application in the command line and not use the RUN button in eclipse?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a similar question - you can work around it with external consoles, batch files and/or remote debugging. There is also a link to the issue in the Eclipse bug DB.

Answer (score 0):

> [System.console](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console())  returns the unique Console object
>   associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any.

you have to test if console is null before using it.