# JavaFX: Where do print statements go when application is running outside IDE?

Tags: printing, ide, output, java-8

When writing code, for debugging purposes, you typically add System.out.println("something to print"), which prints to the output window of the IDE.

When you compile your code to a JAR or an EXE, hence running the application outside the IDE, does the application still print? or do print statements get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're running your application and possibly the system you're running on.

If you're running a JAR using `java -jar Foo.jar` on the command line then `System.out` will direct content to the console in which the program was run.

Java applications that don't use a console are typically run with `javaw` instead of `java`. The `javaw` program runs without a console and, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10401479/1102962), the output stream will be null. This behavior may depend on the JDK and/or the OS.