# How to start the java console when launching an application from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

When I start a java application, the Java Console is started. But when I start a java application from Eclipse, the Java Console does not start on its own. How can I make it start also when I run an application from Eclipse?

Comment: I need the console, because I need to set the debugging level. And I need to run it from Eclipse, because there are a lot of settings which need to be set (Tomcat, jar, sign jars, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [at this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide) .. I think it is exactly what you want.

There is an answer of how to be able to use step-through debugging from Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

What for do you need java console? There is window console in Eclipse IDE where all System.out.println are redirected.

Comment: I need it for a debug situation... is it possible to start the console when I run the application from Eclipse?

Comment: @Jenea - This is not enough if java.io.Console support is required. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Comment: maybe he needs System.in?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the program to start in it's own window. Try running it as an external tool.  The program would be cmd.exe and the argument would be your java command line, e.g. "java -cp c:\myclasspath myProg" and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

First check that no other console is pinned, icon looks like window with a needle in it. This means that no other console except the one that is pinned will show the output. If everything else fails try to reset the java perspective in Eclipse.