# NullPointerException in Console's readLine()

Tags: java, console

This:

```
Console c = System.console();
        String readline;
        String u = c.readLine("%s", "args");
```

Throws a `NullPointerException.` Yet the signature of the method is:

```
 public String readLine(String fmt, Object... args)
```

Why's this exception being thrown?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Console c = System.console();
```

Is `c` null?

[Doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()):

> public static Console console()
>
> Returns the unique Console object
>   associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any.
>
> Returns: The system console, if any,
>   **otherwise null**.

Comment: Oh...how can I get a console object from Netbeans?

Comment: I haven't tried using this call in Netbeans, but you can use remote debugging in Eclipse to get round this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide/105403#105403 I'm sure it is possible to do something similar in Netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

NullPointerException is a RuntimeException, which means it doesn't have to be declared in the method signature.

Comment: It is an answer to the question of why the NPE is thrown, given that the signature doesn't specify any exceptions.  As I read the question, that appeared to be the questioner's main point of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

via: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=487190 for detail

Before using a method it always pays to read the API documents on what the method does. For example docs for the console() method say:

Quote:

> Whether a virtual machine has a
>   console is dependent upon the
>   underlying platform and also upon the
>   manner in which the virtual machine is
>   invoked. If the virtual machine is
>   started from an interactive command
>   line without redirecting the standard
>   input and output streams then its
>   console will exist and will typically
>   be connected to the keyboard and
>   display from which the virtual machine
>   was launched. If the virtual machine
>   is started automatically, for example
>   by a background job scheduler, then it
>   will typically not have a console.
>
> If this virtual machine has a console
>   then it is represented by a unique
>   instance of this class which can be
>   obtained by invoking the
>   System.console() method. If no console
>   device is available then an invocation
>   of that method will return null.of that method will return null.

If you try invoking the program from the command line using the java command then it will have a console and the method should not return null.of that method will return null.

Alternatively, using the Scanner class will work inside of your IDE:

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 4):

Because `System.console()` is `null` in the IDE you are using. Try `java.util.Scanner` instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String u = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: This is an alternate, not an answer. People try to use Console for a reason, and it is for readPassword

Answer (score 2):

Is `c` null somehow?

By the way, your readLine statement is equivalent to `c.readLine("args")` - is that what you intend?

Answer (score 2):

System.console() returned null, it is the only line in that code snippet that could have possibly thrown a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's something strange in the code snippet. You declare a variable called "readline" but you don't initialize it and don't use it.

Is it possible that in the program you somehow use this variable w/o initializing it? (a long shot, I know)