# How to get System Console in Java while using IDE's like Eclipse or NetBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to get System Console in java developing using IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans.
But I am not able to get the same.

If I jar the program and run it via command prompt, its working fine but thats not the case while running it in IDE.

How to get System console object that works with IDE console's ?

Comment: You can't. There is an Eclipse bug ticket opened for it. There is a work around for now that involves you having to emulate the Console when running within Eclipse. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null/11199326#11199326

Comment: In Netbeans there is the same problem. Every time you try to get the Console (System.console()) you get a null.

Comment: Jetbrains IDEA, same problem