# Reading password from Console in java

Tags: java, java-io

I want to read password from console in one my java program. I used

```
 Console newConsole = System.console();
```

But I could able to declare and initialize console object in my class.
I am getting an error message

```
" the method console() is undefined for the type System" and " Console cannot be resolved or is not a type"
```

Hence I thought I don't have latest java version and checked my java version using

```
C:\>java -version
    java version "1.7.0_21"
```

I came to know that I have java 1.7.0_21 which is the latest version but still I am getting error. Anybody could you please help me regarding this.

If I can't use System.console then are there any other method I can use to read password as hidden character from console.

The complete code :

```
  import java.io.console;

  public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            Console newConsole = System.console();

    }
   }
```

I am getting compiler error in **import java.io.console** (java.io.console cannot be resolved) and Console **newConsole = System.console();** (the method console() is undefined for the type System and Console cannot be resolved or is not a type) line.

Comment: Did you add the import statement for `java.io.Console`?

Comment: Please post _all_ of your code for that particular file.

Comment: This Should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159762/how-to-read-password-from-console-without-using-system-console

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Is the compiler the same version as the interpreter?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Thank you for your response. yes I have used the import statement. I am also getting error on that statement.

Comment: @Chris Thompson - Thank you for your response. I have edited and added the code in my question.

Comment: @tbodt - Thank you for your response. I am using SAP Netweaver developer studio IDE. I did not check the version of interpreter. I will check it and add comment on that..

Answer (score 1):

according to javadoc:

Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also    upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. **If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist** and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.

Answer (score 1):

You want `import java.io.Console` instead of `import java.io.console`.

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Console newConsole = System.console();
     }
}
```

That should get it to compile, but what I've found says System.console() will return `null` inside an IDE and to check [this link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that error coming from wrong import would be

```
error: The import java.io.console cannot be resolved
    import java.io.console;

error: Console cannot be resolved to a type
    Console console = System.console();
```

So by fixing a typo as suggested

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          Console newConsole = System.console();
   }
}
```

Will not solve other problem, that is

> the method console() is undefined for the type System" and " Console cannot be resolved or is not a type"

I accidentally get this error working in Kubuntu 14.04 with pre-installed `javac` compiler that is actually

```
gcj-4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

And that compiler is the one that causes problem above.

When I realized that I was *not* actually using `javac` from JDK package, and typed to compile

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac
```

That actually worked, because that compiler was actually from JDK that I've installed, and not [GNU Java Compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) that was the one causing the error

I could not find fast information about packages in GNU compiler, but I know that sometime ago they did not have `System.console()` in some releases.

One can take a look [here](http://builder.classpath.org/japi/openjdk7-classpath.html#err_missing_java_lang), that was re-directed from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/)

The question is so bearded now, and may be in new releases this error should not occur.

But I however pretty sure that error `method console is undefined` is coming not because of `import` errors or typos but rather from the compiler that does not know where to find `System.console()` method.

And although `java` version was printed and looks correct

> C:>java -version
>       java version "1.7.0_21"

It does not matter what `java` version it is, rather what compiler `javac` was used to compile