# Is it true that better to print through Console object - it handles "special characters" better?

Tags: java, character-encoding, console, character, command-prompt

In my book I read following:

```
import java.io.Console;
// better to print thro' Console object - it handles "special characters" better
class SpecialCharHandling {
    public static void main(String []args) {
    // string has three Scandinavian characters
        String scandString = "å, ä, and ö";
    // try printing scandinavian characters directly with println
        System.out.println("Printing scands directly with println: " + scandString);
    // now, get the Console object and print scand characters thro' that
        Console console = System.console();
        console.printf("Printing scands thro' console's printf method: " + scandString);
    }
}
```

> Here is what this program prints: Printing scands directly with

```
Printing scands directly with println: •, •, and ÷ 

Printing scands thro' console's printf method: å, ä, and ö
```

> As you can see from this output, Console’s printf() method (and other
>   methods) have better support for special characters.

I try to launch this application locally. I got a different result:

```
Printing scands directly with println: ├е, ├д, and ├╢
Printing scands thro' console's printf method: Г?, Г¤, and Г?
```

How to explain difference with book ?

Comment: Weird, I get `Printing scands directly with println: å, ä, and ö` and then `System.console()` returns null and I get a NPE... How are you running it?

Comment: @azurefrog For `null` console (unrelated to this), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you, I was unaware of that issue in eclipse.  From the command line I get `Printing scands directly with println: σ, Σ, and ÷` and `Printing scands thro' console's printf method: å, ä, and ö` so it seems to be highly dependent on exactly how you run the program.

Comment: @azurefrog in IDEA I see same issue(null)

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Vince Emigh http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2NxUP8WCRv4/UsVlNmkNOjI/AAAAAAAAA6Q/zR-D5SeZ3ts/s1600/Oracle+Java+SE+7+Certification+OCPJP+7+exam+book.jpg