# How would I receive input from console without blocking?

Tags: java, console, nonblocking

Note: I understand that the console is for debugging and games should use GUI. This is for testing/experience

I'm writing a game that runs at 60fps. Every update, I check to see if the user has entered a `String` command. If so, it gets passed through, but if not, `null` is paas through, and the `null` is ignored.

Scanner is out of the question, since `hasNext()`, the method used to see if there is data to read, can potentially block and causes problems.

I've tried using `BufferedReader.ready()`. Not only did I have problems (never returned `true`), but I've read that it's not recommended for a few reasons.

`BufferedReader.available()` always returned 0, which in the documentation, it state's that `InputStream.available()` will always return 0 unless overriden. Here is my attempt:

```
class Game {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          InputReader reader = new InputReader(System.in);
          int timePerLoop = 1000/30;

          Game game = new Game();
          while(true) {
               long start = System.nanoTime();
               game.update(reader.next());
               long end = System.nanoTime();

               long sleepTime = timePerLoop + ((start - end) / 10000000);
               if(sleepTime > 0)
                    try {
                         Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               else
                    Thread.yield();
          }
     }

     public void update(String command) {
          if(commands != null) {
               //handle command
          }

          //update game
     }
}
```

InputReader.java

```
public class InputReader {
     private InputStream in;

     public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
          in = stream;
     }

     public String next() {
          String input = null;
          try {
               while(in.available > 0) {
                    if(input == null)
                         input = "";

                    input += (char) in.read();
               }
          }catch(IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return input;
     }
}
```

`InputStream` by itself has the same problem as above. I'm not completely sure what type the object stored in `System.in`, but using `available()` yields the same results.

I've tried using the `reader()` from `System.console()`, but `console()` returns null. I've read into the subject, and I am not confused why. This is not the way to do it.

The goal is to check the stream to see if it contains data to read, so I can read the data knowing it won't block.

I do not want to use a separate `Thread` to handle user input, so please don't recommend or ask why.

The input has to be from the console. No new sockets are to be created in the process. I have read a few topics about it, but none of them clearly states a solution. **Is this possible?**

Comment: did you ever got it working?

Answer (score 1):

As you have said yourself, a custom GUI or an additional thread is the correct way to do this. However in absence of that, have you tried using `readLine()` for example: `String inputR = System.console().readLine();`

Some alterations to main():

Replace: `InputReader reader = new InputReader(System.in);` with:
`Console c = System.console();`

Replace: `game.update(reader.next());`
with: `game.update(c.readLine());`

Edit: This thread could also be helpful: [Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console)

Comment: `System.console()` may return null, depending on how the JVM is being started ([System.console() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4203699/2398375)). I actually found out that my example works on my friend's computer. I was running this from my phone (which although it does support console applications, is not fully functional yet). Long story short, it was a JVM problem, and now realize that my question only applies to a very specific platform, not suitable for SO. Thanks for the attempt though :)