# I'm getting a NullPointerException.... i can`t findout the error .please help me to findout the error

Tags: java

```
import java.io.Console;

public class ConcoleInjava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Console c=System.console();

    System.out.println("enter ur passward :");

    char[]ch=c.readPassword();
    String pass=String.valueOf(ch);
    System.out.println(pass);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: Where is the NullPointerException being raised

Comment: `Console` appears to be `null`.  Have you tried running it from the command line

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.console() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

Answer (score 2):

Console object is not getting created,which is why you are getting NPE.

at the line `char[]ch=c.readPassword();`

See Here:- [The Problem may be related to IDE or no console available](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

Possible solution:- [Refer to this issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

Comment: Now that you've found the symptom, do you have a cure?

Comment: @MadProgrammer , knew it  but,was looking for the best possible solution,so provided the link

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the NullPointerException is raised at the `char[]ch=c.readPassword();` because the `Console c` object has no value in it.
Which means, you are asking for the password value of an object which equals to null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your program inside Eclipse you can't get a Console instance.

It is a known eclipse bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Answer (score 0):

As you are not initializing the character array it is giving NullPointerException

```
import java.io.Console;
public class ConcoleInjava {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console c=System.console();
    System.out.println("enter ur passward :");
    char[]ch = new char[int];
    ch = c.readPassword();
    String pass=String.valueOf(ch);
    System.out.println(pass);
}
```

}

In the code in place of "[int]" (line no 6 ) give the size of that array means you are initializing the array. so you wont get the null pointer exception.

Comment: That won't work as your are assigning the char array object to the value of a possible return method after it was instantiated this entails the char array object will lose its attributes in the next line of code after it was instantiated.

Comment: giving the array size i still facing this problem.....

Answer (score 0):

The method call `c.readPassword();` returns `null` if the `end of stream is` `reached`. End of stream means there are no more characters to read in a sense. You may have to do more research on this to gain full clarity from java oracle docs.