# Error with Console.readPassword()

Tags: java

Result is: Error.I think that console is null,I don't know why.Can somebody help me?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Vezbanje {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        Console console = System.console();

        if(console != null) {
            console.printf("Please enter your username: ");
            String username = console.readLine();
            console.printf(username + "\n");

            console.printf("Please enter your password: ");
            char[] passwordChars = console.readPassword();
            String passwordString = new String(passwordChars);

            console.printf(passwordString + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.console() returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

Comment: You can create a Scanner object try reading from console

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine();`

Instead of doing `console.readLine();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is no console available.

From, `System.console()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console())

> Returns: The system console, **if any, otherwise null**.

It returns the console only if there's one. And not always there is a console.

For Eg: While running the code from **Eclipse**, you won't find a console and hence calling `System.console()` would return **null**.