# Node.js child.stdin.write doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, node.js-stream

when I try to run child process and put to it stdin some text it throws error.
here is code of child process:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("started");

        Console console = System.console();

        while (true) {
            String s = console.readLine();
            System.out.println("Your sentence:" + s);
        }
    }
}
```

code of script which run this process:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('java', ['HelloWorld', 'HelloWorld.class']);


child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);


child.stdin.write("tratata\n");

// child.stdin.end();
```

it throws:

```
events.js:161
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:572:26)
```

notice, when I uncomment line with child.stdin.end(); it only ends whithout any reaction

Comment: FWIW `child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');` is not correct. `setEncoding()` is for `Readable` streams, but `child.stdin` is to be used as a `Writable` stream.

Comment: Also, did you try using CRLF instead of LF for line endings (e.g. `child.stdin.write("tratata\r\n");`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing you need to make the script work was to add:

```
process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
```

If you added this before the `child.stdin.write`, that would solve half the problem. The other half had to do with the Java side. If the java program is not launched from a console by typing `java HelloWorld`, then [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) will return null thus you will get a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if you tried to use [`Console.readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine--). To fix, this use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead.

Change your script to this:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const child = spawn('java', ['HelloWorld'], {
    stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr]
});

process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin);
setTimeout(() => {
    child.stdin.write('tratata\n');
}, 1000);
```

Then change your java code to this:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("started");

        try(BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            for (String line = console.readLine(); line != null; line = console.readLine()) {
                System.out.printf("Your sentence: %s\n", line);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

See:

- [NodeJS Spawn Command](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)
- [System.console() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)