# How to make a Gpars Actor to read from console

Tags: groovy, actor, gpars

I have a simple GPars actor:

```
class ConsoleActor extends DefaultActor {

    protected void act() {
        loop {
            react { Msg msg ->
                switch (msg.type) {
                    case MsgType.Read:
                        sender.send(System.console().readLine())
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to send a message to force the actor to read from Console, i get a NPE:

> An exception occurred in the Actor thread Actor Thread 3
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on
>   null object

Why this happens and how to read from console in a GPars Actor?

Comment: I don't think you should be reading from the console from an actor... 

Comment: Also, if you're in a headless environment, `System.console()` will return null

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console--

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[StackOverflow - System Console returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

```
class ConsoleActor extends DefaultActor {

    protected void act() {
        loop {
            react { Msg msg ->
                switch (msg.type) {
                    case MsgType.Read:
                        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String str = input.nextLine();
                        sender.send(str)
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for me.