# Read password from console in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, console, passwords

In Java the `System` static method `console()` returns the object allowing to read from terminal. The `Console` instance returned by that method provides method `readLine()` and `readPassword()`. First one echoing input to the console, but second -- doesn't.

In KotlinJVM application provides top level function `readLine()` to read input from the console, but there is no one to `readPassword()`. Also the `System.console()` returns null.

How I can read password (without echoing) from KotlinJVM application?

I just tried these and got NPE

```
package com.helpchoice.kotlin.fuel.dsl

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        System.console().readPassword("pw:")
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        println(e::class.java.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why System.console() returns null: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203646/869184

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is an IDE problem (see [System.console() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)).

So the only solution recommended: read from System.in if there is no console.

```
val pw = System.console()?.readPassword() ?: readLine()
```

This will show your password while debugging from IDE, but will hide if started from console.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you can start with creating this:

```
val console : Console? = System.console()
val password = console.readPassword("Enter password")
```

Worked for me

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Had to downvote as neither this doesn't even compile nor it solves the problem