# Error while trying to get input in groovy

Tags: groovy, readline

I am very new to groovy, I am using the below piece of code in Groovy console and Eclipse (running it as Groovy script), however getting the below error.

can you please help?

```
println("What is your name ");
def fName = System.console().readLine()
println("Hello" + fName)
```

## Error in Groovy console

```
groovy> print("What is your name ") 
groovy> def fName = System.console().readLine() 
groovy> println("Hello" + fName)
```

What is your name
Exception thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object

```
at ConsoleScript54.run(ConsoleScript54:2)
```

## Error in Eclipse

What is your name 
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
    at sample.run(sample.groovy:2)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Comment: This is an eclipse problem, not related to groovy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null covers a bit.  Since you are trying to learn groovy , you may use groovy console - that is part your groovy installation : http://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html

Comment: Thanks  Jayan, I am already using Groovy console and I have put the error in groovy console in my question

Answer (score 1):

`System.console()` works when running in terminal, but shouldn't work in an IDE, like Eclipse. A better way of getting a single line of input would be `System.in.newReader().readLine()`