# NullPointerException shows up for Console function

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I wrote a simple four-step java program to understand the functioning of Console function but it throws NullPointerException console is used. I have no idea why the error shows up.

The following is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.Console;

public class ConsoleWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Console c =System.console();
        System.out.println("Enter your name ");
        //line 21
        String s=c.readLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome "+s);       
    }
}
```

And this is what I get in the console when I run my program:

```
Enter your name 
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Swapping$1.run(Swapping.java:21)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

Comment: `System.console()` returns null in an online IDE.

Comment: I'm ran the code on Eclipse installed in my computer.

Comment: Run your program from terminal / command prompt instead of Eclipse. It will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null answers your question.

Comment: I tried running the same program via terminal and it worked. Thanks to @salazarin