# I don't understand this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have been reading the possible solutions to this error, but I don't quite understand it, here is the code and the output it gives me:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Console c = System.console();

        System.out.println("¿Cuántas puertas quieres que tenga el coche?"); 
        String numPuertas = c.readLine(); /* Here is the error */
        int numNum = Integer.parseInt(numPuertas);

        if (numNum == 3) {
            System.out.println("Es un coche deportivo");
        } 

        else if (numNum == 5) {
            System.out.println("Es un coche familiar");
        }
    
        else {
            System.out.println("¿Seguro que el coche tiene " + numNum + " puertas?");
        }
    
    }
}
```

Output

```
¿Cuántas puertas quieres que tenga el coche?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.readLine()" because "<local1>" is null
at Ejercicio3.main(Ejercicio3.java:13)
```

But it won't let me answer the question

Comment: Check the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()). It appears that you have no console, which makes `System.console()` return null. Do you use `javaw` to run your app? You should use `java` rather than `javaw` to have a console. The fact that you try to call a method of `c` while it is assigned with `null` causes the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.console() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null). Search for more.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the instance returned by `Console cons = System.console()` to call the method, check whether the instance `cons` is null before executing other processes.

If your Java program wants to interact with cmd under Windows or Terminal under Linux/unix, you can use this Java Console class to do it for you. Starting an application from such an interactive command line returns an available Console instance.

`Java.io.Console` can only be used in the original console where the standard input and output streams are not redirected, it is not available in Eclipse / Idea or other IDE consoles.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. It's as simple as I just had to click on "Run Java" instead of "Run code" in VSCode