# Java Eclipse Taking Command Line Arguments Continously in Running Time

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, command-line-arguments

First of all, I read all related topics and none of them answered my question.
I am developing a program in Java using Eclipse and I need to pass some arguments to the program continously after it starts.
For example somehow i need to give it this command by command line after it starts  to execute:

`CreateTable Students 2 10 10`

And then I must be able to give more commands such as :

`AddRecord Students Jack 1456`

Run Configurations of Eclipse does not solve the problem since I can give arguments to the program only once by using Run Configurations. But I need to do it multiple lines?
Anyone has a solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible in Eclipse according to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide) (which also lists possible workarounds). **Update** it's not possible to allocate `System.console()`, that much is true

But it does work with System.in (thanks Stephen C):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type something please:");
    line = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: That's about what `System.console()` gives you when you are running within Eclipse.  You should be able to type stuff at the Eclipse console for your application and read it using your application's `System.in`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should read a sequence of commands from an inputstream, which might be connected to a Scanner (for live input) or a file (for runtime testing.)

Comment: Reading them from a file sounds fine but it creates some problems with my code. And I don't know what Scanner is but live input seems what i need :)

Comment: What you need is not command line parameters, it's text input from the console. [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Scanner.html) is the standard Java class to input data from the console or another input stream.