# System.console() returns null from Eclipse but fine with Command Prompt

Tags: java, console

When I use System.console from Eclipse Helios, it always returns null.

However, when I use it directly from command line (i.e. compiling and executing a java source code manually from command prompt), I do get a Console object.

To know, why this happens I checked [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) link. According to it, when I run my Java code from Eclipse, a background job scheduler must be starting my JVM. What does this mean?

And how differently is my JVM started when I start it from command line?

I also checked [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html) link. Here McDowell says that cmd.exe is a console device. So then I am again confused that exactly is a console device?

Comment: you can find your answer from this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 6):

Because it is a bug [#122429](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429) of eclipse

Answer (score 2):

`System.console()` returns null if there is no console.

You can work round this either by [adding a layer of indirection to your code](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html) or by running the code in an external console and [attaching a remote debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide).

Also, According to the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html):

> If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.