# why console.readpassword does not work in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to get the input from the from the user (hidden) 
and trying to print that password, but the console is `null` and getting `NullPointerException`.

Is `readPassword()` supported in java? What is the substitute for this?

```
Console cons;
if((cons = System.console()) != null) {
    char[] password = null;

    try {   
        System.out.println("Enter the password :");
        password=cons.readPassword();    
        System.out.println("Your password is" + new String(password));
    } finally {
        if(password != null) {
            java.util.Arrays.fill(password,' ');
        }
    }
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("can't get password...No console");
}
```

Comment: If `readPassword` didn't exist, you wouldn't get a `NullPointerException`. You wouldn't even be able to compile.

Comment: What line throws the NPE?

Comment: The problem is that eclipse doesn't support `System.console()`! For more info see: [System.console() returns null from Eclipse but fine with Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8969990/8097737) and [java.io.Console support in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104254/8097737)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.console() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is an open bug in Eclipse that leads to System.console being NULL. Related question:

[How to read password from console without using System.console()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159762/how-to-read-password-from-console-without-using-system-console)

Still open bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Also see the duplicates of that bug.