# Automate console inputs from external input file?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does eclipse have the ability to load external file that contains thousands of lines of console commands and execute them?

I am debugging a program which requires a lot of commands for setup, it will be a great time saver if I don't have to type those commands every single time. (without modifying existing java code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug console applications in Eclipse by leveraging the remote debugger. Then the console commands will be executed through a batch file. I suspect that is preferred, anyway, with thousands of lines of console commands. Error messages can then be captured from the output generated while running the batch.

Here is more detail, [answered in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide).