# Java Unicode String is null?

Tags: java, unicode, null, runtime-error, unicode-string

I want to print a box into the Java console using Unicode characters, but for some reason it gives me this runtime error:

```
--------------------Configuration: PacManGame - JDK version 1.7.0_25 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Scoreboard.genTopLine(Scoreboard.java:35)
    at Scoreboard.<init>(Scoreboard.java:17)
    at PacManGame.main(PacManGame.java:36)

Process interrupted by user.
```

code: http://pastebin.com/nuAsH857

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug yor program? Which value is null iin line 35 of class Scoreboard?

Comment: @Zavior Did you even read the code? I know it's null, but it's null even after I set it.

Comment: @Jens Did you even read the code? I know it's null, but it's null even after I set it.

Comment: @user3580294 I know what a null pointer is.

Comment: "and how do I fix it". A debugger would have served you well here.

Comment: @user3580294 You didn't look at my code either, did you? I set the variable, it shouldn't be null anymore.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the variable. And yes, I did look at your code.

Comment: Can you post some code which we could actually use to reproduce your problem? The only NPE I can get is the one from `System.console().writer()` because `System.console()` returns `null` if there is no console, like if application was executed with `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe` (like most of IDEs does to run code).

Comment: @Pshemo http://pastebin.com/nuAsH857 is in the main post

Comment: I saw it, that is why I said I got NPE on `System.console().writer()`. What I meant is some code with `main` method which we could use to get exactly same exception you are seeing. For now I can't reproduce your problem so will not be able to help you.

Comment: @Pshemo oh. http://pastebin.com/GtnTJiqh

Comment: Actually I used this code to create previously mentioned NPE. When I run it using `javaw.exe` console wasn't created so `System.console()` returned `null` (as expected). When I run id via `java.exe` it worked fine, but I am using Java 8 so that may be somehow relevant :/

Comment: @Pshemo I'm running it in JCreator

Answer (score 0):

`topline` is actually NOT null - it's perfectly fine.
The problem is the use of `System.console()` which returns `null` (and hence you get NPE on `.writer()`).

Use `System.out.println()` instead and it'll work just fine.

An explanation as to why `System.console()` doesn't work in your IDE can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986071/1057429)**

Comment: But when I do that the unicode prints incorrectly.

Comment: @AidanEdwards make sure that your IDE is set to use UTF-8. Go to  "Settings | File Encodings"

Comment: Do you know where it would be in JCreator?

Comment: @AidanEdwards nope...

Comment: Another thing you can try: `byte[] utf8Bytes = topLine.getBytes("UTF8");
        String topLine = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");` and then print it using SOP.

Comment: Still just prints ????????????????????. :(

Comment: Try running from command line.

Comment: I've never done that before and can't seem to find a good tutorial on doing so. Could you link one?

Comment: Go to the folder that contains your java file (in command line) and run `javac Scoreboard.java` and then `java Scoreboard`

Comment: It says it isn't a recodnized command

Comment: Google "how to set my classpath java" and the name of your operating-system