# Why Console in Eclipse or IntelliJ always null?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, null, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.Console() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203646/system-console-returns-null)

Code:

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Console is.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

always No console. Why ? How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: It is not dublicate at all. in 104254 there is nothing about IntelliJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have any console associated.

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any, otherwise null

EDIT:

From [Console javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).

Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.