# Why does System.console() return null for a command line app?

Tags: java, console, console-application, system-calls

I am working on a legacy app which depends on user command line input:

```
String key = System.console().readLine("Please enter the license key: ");
```

However, I am getting a `NullPointerException` because `System.console()` gives me a null.

Why does `System.console()` return null for a command line app?  It happens when running it out of the terminal as well as IDE.

Comment: "The system console, if any, otherwise null."  how do i eliminate the "otherwise" scenario?

Comment: What terminal, what OS?

Comment: OSX using the Terminal app.  IDE = IntelliJ

Comment: IntelliJ [doesn't seem to handle the console properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423256/why-console-in-eclipse-or-intellij-always-null).

Comment: same happens with the Terminal...

Comment: According to the API:

If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.

Answer (score 3):

If you start java from a terminal window, then it *really should* work, even though I haven't tried on OSX.

If you run a simple test using java directly from the terminal, does it work?

```
echo 'public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) {System.console().printf("hello world%n");}}' >Test.java && javac Test.java && java Test
```

Expected output:

```
hello world
```

If it doesn't work, then sorry, no console support on your platform.

However, if it works, and your program doesn't then there is a problem with how your program is started.

Check how the java binary started? Is it started from a shell script? Check that stdin/stdout have not been  redirected or piped into something, and possibly also that it's not started in the background.

ex: This will probably make System.console() return null.

```
java Test | tee >app.log
```

and this:

```
java Test >/tmp/test.log
```

This seems to work on my machine (linux)

```
java Test &
```

Neither does it seem as if `System.setOut`, `System.setErr` or `System.setIn` affects the console, even after a couple of gc's and finalizers.

---

*However:*

Closing (the original) `System.out` or `System.in` will disable the `console` too.

```
echo 'public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.close();System.console().printf("hello world%n");}}' >Test.java && javac Test.java && java Test
```

Expected output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test.main(Test.java:1)
```

So; scan your code for places where it closes streams, or passes System.out somewhere it might get closed.

Comment: it does.  the self-contained one-liner test is great, BTW

Comment: so we have a situation where `System.console()` sometimes returns null and sometimes it doesn't.  i am trying to understand why it ever returns a null...

Comment: I've updated the answer. How is java started when you start it from the terminal?

Comment: using the `java` command with a few JVM options and a bunch of params

Comment: Perhaps System.out is closed by accident.

Answer (score 1):

To read from Standard input (command line input) you must use some kind of stream reader to read the System.in stream.
An InputStreamReader initialised by

```
    InputStreamReader(System.in)
```

lets you read character by character.
However, I suggest wrapping this with a BufferedReader:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inputLine = reader.readLine();
```

Must import

```
    java.io.*;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with standard input.  The question is asking why System.console() returns null when the program is run from the command line.

Comment: @VGR It is just providing an alternative that is more likely to work,.  As also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console The bufferedReader approach is more reliable as it will work on IDEs and does not depend on where java is run from.