# Getting input from user in Console without using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to know about other ways of getting input from users using other classes like `BufferedReader`,etc rather than using Scanner class. So, was there any other way of getting input from the user? If so, was it efficient than `Scanner` class?

Comment: System.in is an InputStream. You can read from it directly or use any class that wraps it, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using the Java SE6 or higher then you can make use of `Console` clas

```
   Console console = System.console();
   if (console==null){
      System.out.print("console not available ");
   }else {
      String line = console.readLine("Enter name :");
      System.out.print("your name :"+line);
   }
```

Comment: @Gowtham updated answer. but are you running this in eclipse then it might not give the system console. It is [bug in eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429)
Although there is workaround this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide)

Comment: If possible please add that workaround for eclipse and also the way to run this in command line to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it simply by the following steps:

1. Use the `BufferedReader` Class and wrap it with the `InputStreamReader` Class.

   ```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
   //string str = br.readLine(); //for string input
   int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // for Integer Input
   ```
2. Now since the `readLine` method throws an `IOException` you need to catch it. The whole code will look like this:

   ```
   try {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
       //string str = br.readLine();     //for string input
       int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // for Integer Input
   } catch(IOException ioe) {
       ioe.PrintStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.in` directly, like this:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Although this may be a little faster than using the `Scanner`, it's not an apples-to-apples comparison: `Scanner` provides more methods for tokenizing the input, while `BufferedReader` can split your input into lines, without tokenizing it.

Comment: Was it efficient than Scanner Class?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

to create a reader for `System.in`, and you can use `stdin.readLine()` or something to get what you want.

Using a `BufferedReader` is MUCH more efficient than using a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Here for example...

```
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);

int num , num2;
String str[]=new String[2];

System.out.print("Please Enter Your First Number:");
str[0] = stdin.readLine();
System.out.print("Please Enter Your Second Number:");
str[1] = stdin.readLine();

num = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
num2 = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

> A user can input data at the time of execution of the program without using a scanner class, and this can be done by using the following program.

```
 class Demo
  { 
   public static void main(String ar[])
    {
     int ab = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
     int ba = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
     int res = ab+ba;
     System.out.print(res);
    }
  }
```

> This is a basic program where a user can input data at the time of execution and get the desired result. You can add, subtract, Multiply, divide and concatenate strings, in CMD and a user can input data after compiling the java program i.e at the time of calling the class file. You just need to call the class file and then enter the data after a space.

`C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop>java Demo 5 2`

> Here ab= 5 and ba= 2. A user can have any number or string if he wants.