# Why does my Java program work in console and not in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, console

I wanted to know why does my Java program work in console when I do :

> javac Main.java
>
> java Main

...and not in Eclipse, as I have this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at codePin.main.main(main.java:48)
>   --> char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter pin: ");

Here's my code :

```
package codePin;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class main {


    static public boolean readPinsData(File dataFile, ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        boolean err = false;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
            String line;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                try {
                    data.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    err = true;
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = true;
        }

        return err;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("APPLICATIONS BESOINS");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        Console console = System.console();

        System.out.println(console == null);

        int pinSize = 0;
        int nbTry = 0;
        boolean authenticated = false;


        do {
            do {

                char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter pin: "); //This is the line causing the error 
                pinSize = passwordArray.length;

                if (pinSize != 4) { 

                    System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Checking...");
                }

                ArrayList<Integer> pins = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
                readPinsData(new File("bdd.txt"), pins); 



                String[] thePins = new String[pins.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {
                    thePins[i] = pins.get(i).toString();
                }

                String passEntered = String.valueOf(passwordArray);

                for (int i = 0; i < thePins.length; i++) {                      
                    if (passEntered.equals(thePins[i]) && pinSize == 4) {
                        System.out.println(":)");
                        authenticated = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } while (pinSize != 4); 
            if (!authenticated && pinSize == 4) { 

                System.out.println(":(");
                nbTry++;
            }
        } while (nbTry < 3 && !authenticated);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added `System.out.println(console == null);` at the beggining of my public static void main method just to check, and it does actually return true in the console.

So my question is : how to initialize the console in Eclipse so my code could work ?
Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104254/java-io-console-support-in-eclipse-ide

Comment: I added the line causing the error.

Comment: Thanks JP Moresmau, I tried to do as it says in your link, but it does not work. I still have this error and it is impossible to debug this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `System.console()` will return the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any, while eclipse does not have an unique console.

You should try to use `Scanner` or `System.in` to get the console input

Comment: I do not understand how to replace it in my program. I have error when I do that.

Comment: For example, you could use `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); String password = scanner.next();`

Comment: You can add a line like `System.out.print("Enter pin:");` before the input code.

Comment: Yep that's what I did, my question was stupid sorry.

Comment: @FlorentP That's fine :)

Comment: I was thinking, do I need to close the scanner somewhere in the code ?

Comment: @FlorentP When you don't use System.in, you can close it.

Comment: That's weird, when I add a "scanner.close()" in my code, I have a java.util.NoSuchElementException at "java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)", at "java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)", and at "String password = scanner.next()"; in my code.

Comment: `scanner.close()` will close `System.in` and `System.in` is static, so if you close it at some place, you cannot use it any more.

Comment: I see, so where do you suggest me to close it ? Or I could use "scanner = new Scanner(System.in);" instead of "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);" right ? This way I don't have to close it.

Comment: I always use a static scanner and close it at the end of main method if more than one object needs to use it.

Comment: And in your code, you should add `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` out of your loop

Comment: Ok perfect. I put the scanner outside the two do{}while loops and I have no problems anymore. Thanks again.